# Linking external JSON-LD schema (from Schema.org)

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld, script

I have a schema in JSON-LD as per Schema.org. When it was inline (within `<script>` tags), the [Google structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) recognised the schema successfully.

If I link it externally, the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) doesn't recognise it. For example:

```html
<script src="json/main-schema.json" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

Is this something I should be worried about?

---

How I had the working schema (example from Schema.org):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1212",
  "contactType" : "customer service"
    } ] }
</script>
```

External schema layed out in `main-schema.json`, linked with:

```html
<script src="json/main-schema.json" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

```json
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1212",
  "contactType" : "customer service"
    } ] }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute URL rather than a relative one? While I don't know the answer to this, a quick work-around if you want the data being in a external file is simply to put the contents within a php file...then you just call the file in the footer using `<?php include 'json.php';?>`, just a suggestion mind.

Comment: @Unor said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30880613/1892635 you need to use `<link>` not `<script>`  since `src=""` is not valid. But Google only supports script... so looks like it has to be inline.

Comment: @SimonHayter - yeah, it normally is, I removed it for the example.  Thanks for the other link - sorry I didn't see it!

Comment: I highly recommend using Google Tag Manager to meet this requirement. After futzing around for more than an hour testing out the various scenarios described here and elsewhere, I resolved the issue in about 15 minutes using a pageview trigger and HTML markup tag. Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`script` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/semantics-scripting.html#the-script-element) can be used for two things:

- dynamic/classic **scripts**
- **data**

And for data, the spec defines:

> When used to include data blocks, the data must be embedded inline […]

So you may use the `src` attribute only for scripts, not for data.

→ As JSON-LD is data, you have to inline it.

While [linking a JSON-LD file is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880613/1591669) with the `link` element, the Schema.org sponsoring search engines don’t seem to support it.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data):

> […] Also, Google can read JSON-LD data when it is **dynamically injected into the page's contents**, such as by JavaScript code or embedded widgets in your content management system.

Which suggests that, while yo cannot link external json-ld data, you can still load it dynamically and inject it to the DOM. This might be good enough for your use case, as you can load static JavaScript on your page that will then inject the JSON-LD into the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

This *may*, or *may not* help, but take a look at how [Trevor Fox did it](https://trevorfox.com/2017/03/json-ld-files-with-javascript/):

```
<script>

$.getJSON( "/your-schema-file.jsonld", function( data ) {
$( "<script/>", {
"type": "application/ld+json",
"html": JSON.stringify(data)
}).appendTo( "head" );
});

</script>
```

This may be your best option. He used [jQuery version 3.1.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js) for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

[unor’s answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/104051/10884) sums it up, but I also want to add:

From the spec:

> Setting the [`type`] attribute to any other value *[other than a JavaScript MIME type]* means that the script is a **data block**, which is not processed. None of the `<script>` attributes (except `type` itself) have any effect on data blocks. Authors must use a valid MIME type that is not a JavaScript MIME type to denote data blocks.

So, in other words, if you have a `<script>` with a `type` attribute set to anything other than `text/javascript` (or an equivalent [JavaScript MIME type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/semantics-scripting.html#javascript-mime-type)), then all attributes, including `src`, will have no effect.